How to implement ESN layers or more generally reservoir computing approach in MATLAB DDPG agent
Is it possible to use echo state neural networks and generally reservoir computing approach as actor and critic networks in MATLAB with DDPG agent? Does MATLAB support this feature? If yes, how to do it and also from what version of MATLAB is it supported and If no, how do you suggest to implement it manually?
Any Suggestion ?
